# .NET Weird character encoding issue

Tags: .net, utf-8, character-encoding

Our globalization mechanism stores error messages in a SQL 2005 DB.

Some of the error messages are used as subjects on email messages sent to the development team.

Recently, with no clear reason, we started receiving emails with strangely encoded subjects, such as:

> =?utf-8?B?Qm1mQm92ZXNwYS5Qb3NUcmFkaW5nRXNwZWNpZmljYWNhbyAtIFN1Y2Vzc28gbm8gcmVwcm
>   9jZXNzYW1lbnRvLiBEYXRhIFByZWfDo28gPSAzMS8wMy8yMDEwIDAwOjAwOjAwIC0gTsO6bWVyby
>   BkbyBFdmVudG8gZGUgTmVnw7NjaW8gPSAxMDAyIC0gQ8OzZGlnbyBOYXR1cmV6YSBkYSBPcGVyY
>   cOnw6NvID0gQyAtIFNlcn...

We don't have any clue on the reason this is happening, nor which encoding pattern is being used here (maybe utf-8?).

I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is UTF-8 reencoded as Base64

```
("BmfBovespa.PosTradingEspecificacao - Sucesso no reprocessamento. Data Pregão = 31/03/2010 00:00:00 - Númer...)
```